# How can I ping a server port with PHP?

Tags: php, ping

I want a PHP script which allows you to ping an IP address and a port number (`ip:port`). I found a similar script but it works only for websites, not `ip:port`.

```
<?php

function ping($host, $port, $timeout) 
{ 
  $tB = microtime(true); 
  $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
  if (!$fP) { return "down"; } 
  $tA = microtime(true); 
  return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms"; 
}

//Echoing it will display the ping if the host is up, if not it'll say "down".
echo ping("www.google.com", 80, 10);

?>
```

I want this for a game server.

The idea is that I can type in the IP address and port number, and I get the ping response.

Comment: Use [socket connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php) or see if your server supports tcp://<ip> urn

Comment: ping uses ICMP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php

Comment: @Panagiotis that's what he's doing...

Comment: Ping can`t "ping port". Author possibly asks about measuring delay between request to a port made and answer received.

The question itself is very confusing and must not have the tag "ping". 

Plus, server time to serve request may vastly vary in that case. I tried it for 80 port and it gives much more delay, than ICMP ping. This is true for other ports / services. Question has nothing common with network ping. Very confusing.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800680/pinging-ip-with-a-port-returns-nothing-php-apache) pretty much sums up the problem with your question.

> If what you want to do is find out whether a given host will accept
>   TCP connections on port 80, you can do this:
>
> ```
> $host = '193.33.186.70'; 
> $port = 80; 
> $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
> if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
>    // It worked 
> } else {
>    // It didn't work 
> } 
> fclose($fp);
> ```
>
> For anything other than TCP it will be more difficult (although since
>   you specify 80, I guess you are looking for an active HTTP server, so
>   TCP is what you want). TCP is sequenced and acknowledged, so you will
>   implicitly receive a returned packet when a connection is successfully
>   made. Most other transport protocols (commonly UDP, but others as
>   well) do not behave in this manner, and datagrams will not be
>   acknowledged unless the overlayed Application Layer protocol
>   implements it.
>
> The fact that you are asking this question in this manner tells me you
>   have a fundamental gap in your knowledge on [Transport Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer) protocols.
>   You should read up on [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), as well as the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osi_model).

Also, here's a [slightly cleaner](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/check-your-server-status-a-basic-ping-with-php/) version to ping to hosts.

```
// Function to check response time
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file      = fsockopen ($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file) $status = -1;  // Site is down
    else {
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: Note: that is a quote from the linked question, please do not edit it away thinking it is a code formatting error. I usually put relevant quotations from links in my posts for historicity and in case of link rot, thank you! :)

Answer (score 21):

In case the OP really wanted an ICMP-Ping, there are some proposals within the User Contributed Notes to `socket_create()` [[link]](http://php.net/manual/de/function.socket-create.php), which use raw sockets. Be aware that on UNIX like systems root access is required.

Update: note that the `usec` argument has no function on windows. Minimum timeout is 1 second.

In any case, this is the code of the top voted ping function:

```php
function ping($host, $timeout = 1) {
    /* ICMP ping packet with a pre-calculated checksum */
    $package = "\x08\x00\x7d\x4b\x00\x00\x00\x00PingHost";
    $socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => $timeout, 'usec' => 0));
    socket_connect($socket, $host, null);
    $ts = microtime(true);
    socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
    if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
        $result = microtime(true) - $ts;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    socket_close($socket);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The OP does explicitly state that he wants to use a port

Comment: changed the $package var to $package = "\x08\x00\x19\x2f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x70\x69\x6e\x67";                    got better results on windows when the IP timed out. This was from the documentation in your link. Thanks

Comment: @icc97 OP might not know the difference between ICMP and TCP, so he might falsely assume that *some* port was necessary to ping.

Answer (score 6):

Test different ports:

```
$wait = 1; // wait Timeout In Seconds
$host = 'example.com';
$ports = [
    'http'  => 80,
    'https' => 443,
    'ftp'   => 21,
];

foreach ($ports as $key => $port) {
    $fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errCode, $errStr, $wait);
    echo "Ping $host:$port ($key) ==> ";
    if ($fp) {
        echo 'SUCCESS';
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: $errCode - $errStr";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}


// Ping example.com:80 (http) ==> SUCCESS
// Ping example.com:443 (https) ==> SUCCESS
// Ping example.com:21 (ftp) ==> ERROR: 110 - Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
echo exec('ping -n 1 -w 1 72.10.169.28');
```

Comment: exec is a dangerous function and should be disabled by default in your php.ini.

Comment: what about the port where im gona put it

Comment: @markus-tharkun Agreed. But it is possible to protect it. If you are simply using an input such as an IP, transform IP to int and whatever and check it but yes it is true.

Comment: But you don't need exec for this task.

Comment: @markus what makes it dangerous? or is ONLY it if you pass user input to exec?

Comment: @Brandito not true. If an attacker somehow manages to run arbitrary php code, it can do a lot of damage with exec enabled (even if he is not a priviledged user it could excalate and become root). In a production environment it's safe only if disabled

Answer (score 5):

```
function ping($ip){
    $output = shell_exec("ping $ip");
    var_dump($output);
}
ping('127.0.0.1');
```

UPDATE: 
If you pass an hardcoded IP (like in this example and most of the real-case scenarios), this function can be enough.

But since some users seem to be very concerned about safety, please remind to **never** pass user generated inputs to the `shell_exec` function:
If the IP comes from an untrusted source, at least check it [with a filter](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_ip.asp) before using it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Well I like it! Simple and to the point. Does what the question asks. Put an IP in and get an output!

Comment: @Adsy2010 so do you know what will happen if my $ip is ``$ip = "-n 1 -w 1 localhost; rm -rf /home/;"`` in this case?

Comment: Which is why you would hardcode what goes in and out of the function...

Comment: @RichardRodriguez He's passing the argument straight from the source file, this is a hardcoded value. If you were accepting user input, your comment would be relevant, however, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function

```
 exec("ping ".$ip);
```

[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101739) an example

Comment: exec is a dangerous function and should be disabled by default in your php.ini.

Comment: you're right, but many time exec is the simple way to solve problems :D. For sure I must control and sanitize everything I will put in exec function.

Comment: exec is only dangerous if you're crazy enough to blindly throw user input in there

Comment: @KennethWilke not true. If an attacker somehow manages to run arbitrary php code, it can do a lot of damage with exec enabled (even if he is not a priviledged user it could excalate and become root). In a production environment it's safe only if disabled

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any exec or shell_exec hacks to do that, it is possible to do it in PHP. The book 'You want to do WHAT with PHP?' by Kevin Schroeder, show's how.

It uses sockets and the `pack()` function which lets you read and write binary protocols. What you need to do is to create an ICMP packet, which you can do by using the 'CCnnnA*' format to create your packet.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of suggestions of creating a ping via socket_create on the PHP [socket-create manual page usernotes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#usernotes). However it does require root permissions in linux to run it.

Comment: ONE BIG NOTE . to be able to create an ICMP packet in linux , you have to work with RAW sockets and packets , which needs administrative prevs . this means you need to run apache as root to be able to do that ! . it's safer to just exec then !

Answer (score 0):

socket_create needs to be run as root on a UNIX system with;

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to send ICMP packets in php you can take a look at this [Native-PHP ICMP ping implementation](http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/files/php_icmp_ping_55-16), but I didn't test it.

**EDIT:**

Maybe the site was hacked because it seems that the files got deleted, there is [copy in archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180325030408/http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/files/php_icmp_ping_55-16) but you can't download the tar ball file, there are no contact email only contact form, but this will not work at archive.org, we can only wait until the owner will notice that sit is down.