# connect to a server with PHP and see if that server can ping another

Tags: php, network-programming, ping

I personally don't see how this can be done even though these are my servers. But I want to know if my servers can reach external sites--ping a generic website for example--have outgoing communication. That is, I want to use execute a PHP script on one server, connecting to another of my servers, and test if the second server can ping a website, for example. So I know how to use PHP on the server my script is executing from to ping a website with fopensocket. I just don't know how to set this up to test another server's pingability. I mean I have the credentials but the only way is to have my script on each and every server and then reach the script and execute them. That is not what I want. I want to do this from the one/external server and just feed my script the ip/port/uid/pwd of the server I want to test.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841635/how-to-ping-a-server-with-php

Comment: build a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API and secure it with [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: Why bother with PHP? Just `ssh server "ping ip"`

Comment: Because my dashboard is created in PHP. And this is not a duplicate of that question. That question asks how you ping another server/port. I asked how you testing ping on another server/port to yet a third location like a website. I am on server A. I want to test server B's ability to ping a website on server C.

Comment: OK, so just run the ping through ssh2_exec().

Comment: Yesh ssh2_exec looks like it will do it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes using PHP's ssh2 worked.

Answer (score 0):

An easy API would look something like:

SERVER1:

```
// get response from server2
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.server2.com/api.php?method=ping&ip=IP&port=PORT&uid=UID&pwd=PWD');
// do json_decode() if response is json string
```

SERVER2 (api.php):

```
// respond to API call
if (isset($_GET['method']) && $_GET['method'] == 'ping') {
    // get other params and do your ping function
    echo $pingresult; // perhaps a json encoded array
    exit;
}
```

There is no security so you could send an API password or do it with OAuth or [HMAC](http://www.layer7tech.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-hmac-api-security)

Comment: So the only way is to put a file/script on the second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, etc servers and call it? execute it?

Comment: or try it with a SSH php extension/library [http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/) or [http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: An OAuth-wrapped REST API that requires an active PHP-enabled web service on every machine? That's kinda overkill to get a ping, don't you think?