# How to check ping between client and server in php?

Tags: php

I have a problem, I need to check the connection between client server, i need to get  the response time in ms between the client and a "x" server with php, how I can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841635/how-to-ping-a-server-port-with-php

Comment: i have tried that script, but it returns me the response time between my server and the "x" server, i need to check the reponse time bteween the client and other server!

Comment: I would here something write with javascript. You start a simple request to a server, and store the local time in miliseconds. After the response you can check how long has it taken.

Comment: So, what are you asking is client (running the HTML/JS) to request something from another server and get the ms between. Try to make an ajax call from client to X server or to your server, and that server to the X server, then return the ms.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers to your question. Depending on the answer you will get slightly different results. I have found a jsfiddle that pings servers from Javascript and forked it to include the timing. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/x6r4o5hv/1/

The bit that pings is this:

```
this.img = new Image();
this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
```

The timing is done like this:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
// now do something that takes time here
var finish = new Date().getTime();
var responsetime = 'responded in '+(finish-start)+' ms';
```

This code needs a lot of work to be useable, but it shows the principle.