# How to ping a domain from another location?

Tags: terminal, debian, ping

Is there anyway to ping a web domain from another location in command line ?

I found some websites who provide this kind of services but was wondering if I can do this from terminal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search online ping site; for example i found [helloacm](http://helloacm.com)

i wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e $(curl -s https://helloacm.com/api/ping/?host=${1:-"yahoo.com"})
```

run and output is:

```
/tmp$ ./siteping anubis.ir
"PING anubis.ir (5.56.133.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host4.azaronline.com (5.56.133.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from host4.azaronline.com (5.56.133.10): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from host4.azaronline.com (5.56.133.10): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=14.8 ms

--- anubis.ir ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min\/avg\/max\/mdev = 14.849\/14.888\/14.951\/0.109 ms
"
```

---

OR you can write mini php script and upload it on your site..

then run it with `curl` from terminal

for example see this link's [link1](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030789/pinging-an-ip-address-using-php-and-echoing-the-result) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800680/pinging-ip-with-a-port-returns-nothing-php-apache)

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. I thought there was a way to execute the ping command from another server than localhost but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain's server firewall allows it you can use

```
ping www.domain.com
```

Of course it's only an example, the top level domain doesn't have to be '.com' 
If ICMP is not allowed, you'll get timeouts.